# Decode JWT in golang jwt-go

Tags: go, jwt, jwt-go

What's the equivalent of this code (https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) in golang --- jwt-go library

```
  DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
```

in golang's jwt-go library, when I have to parse the token I need to have the verification key which is not required in the java library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs [at](https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#Parser.ParseUnverified):

```golang
func (p *Parser) ParseUnverified(tokenString string, claims Claims) (token *Token, parts []string, err error)
```

> WARNING: Don't use this method unless you know what you're doing.
>
> This method parses the token but doesn't validate the signature. It's only ever useful in cases where you know the signature is valid (because it has been checked previously in the stack) and you want to extract values from it.

---

[[example]](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/master/parser_test.go#L270)